# Urllib2 get specific element

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a web-page and I want to get the `<div class="password">` element using urllbi2 in Python without using Beautiful Soup.

My code so far:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
link = "http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password"
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/')
contents = response.read('password')
```

It gives an error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `urllib2` doesn't support that operation; you don't need to use Beautiful Soup, but you'll need more than `urllib2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `decode()` the response with `utf-8` as it states in the `Network` tab:

[image: out]

**Hence**:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
link = "http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password"
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/')
output = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print(output)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
YOIYEDGXPU
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want bs4 you say but you could use requests

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.chiquitooenterprise.com/password')
print(r.text)
```